# Want to create visual table in python with ASCII symbols

Tags: python, string, text, datatable, alignment

I got a project in school to make a python program for a hotel management system. In a specific part I found to make cancellation slip in the following format.
[Refer to format 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpzRW.jpg)

Please tell how to make a format like this. I tried to make table using prettytable module but didn't get the desired results. I am new to python so try to suggest an easy way. Specifically I want to know how to create a self made table in a short way. I want the columns and rows merged as is in the image. For example so that I can merge two cells of a table. The table doesn't need to be fancy I just want the strings aligned properly looking neat and clean.

Comment: "I tried to make table using prettytable module but didn't get the desired results"
Please show what you got and describe what's wrong with it

Comment: The left end boundary of a row is not aligned that is it is going out of table. If you permit I can post a picture of that too.

Comment: That's what I'm asking for